# Google PageSpeed stops some WordPress pages from rendering fully

Tags: wordpress, nginx, php, pagespeed, google-pagespeed

So I've got PageSpeed on top of Nginx serving a pretty simple Wordpress install.

This problem seemed to coincide with upgrading to Wordpress 4.2.2; however, after downgrading to 4.1.5 to see if this was the issue, it turned out not to be the case.

Normally I wouldn't blame PageSpeed, but using ?PageSpeed=off in the URL fixes the issue completely. And just to be clear -- there's no cache in the admin area.

Another odd thing is that it only seems to effect Pages (as opposed to Posts) in the CMS, so it seems like PageSpeed might have some conflict with scripts/styles/something specific to Pages.

I am currently baffled, so any suggestions are appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

Open the file "pagespeed.conf" search for:
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel PassThrough

uncomment this line and change it to:
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel CoreFilters (is save for most websites)

if this line above not helps try to change into:
ModPagespeedRewriteLevel OptimizeForBandwidth (stronger guarantee of safety)

**see also the online reference about this subject at PageSpeed:** https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/module/config_filters?hl=nl